# Listener\Watch on "disabled" in pure JavaScript\JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

I have the following elements in html(and others):

```
<div id="MyDiv">
   <input id="MyCb" type="checkbox">
   <font id="MyCaption">Some Text</font>
</div>
```

I want that every time i disable an element like that:

```
document.getElementById("MyDiv").disabled = isDisabled;
```

the listener will raise the following event:

```
function OnDisabled(disabledElement)  
{  
    if (SomeCondition)  
    {  
       // Do Something
    }  
}
```

I know it can be done with "watch" in AngularJs. However I need to do it in pure JavaScript. jQuery is the last resort.

Comment: Why not use a function to disable elements, and it can call your listener function?

Comment: @Barmar This is actually what I do today. But I want a better way to do it so if I have other places that disable elements besides this function, it will get there eventually